# 2D Dictionary - while True Loop is overwriting all Key Values

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I am using a combination of while True and for loops to generate a 2D Python dictionary but the while loop is overwriting the values for all keys rather than the latest key value. Can someone please explain this behaviour to me.

'''

```
MokeDex = {}
MokeBeast = {"type":None, "specialmove":None,  "startingHP":None,"startingMP":None}

while True:
  name = input("Input your beast's name >")
  for key in MokeBeast.keys():
    MokeBeast[key] = input(f"Input your beast's {key} >")

  #print(MokeBeast)
  MokeDex[name]= MokeBeast
  #print(MokeDex)
  check = input("Do you want to add another beast? y/n>")
  if check == "n":
    break

#If I use the following snippet in the while True loop instead of (MokeDex[name]=      MokeBeast) then it works
 #type = input("Type > ").title()
 #hp = int(input("HP > "))
 #mp = int(input("MP > "))
 #mokedex[name] = { "type": type, "hp": hp, "mp": mp}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this behavior is because of how Python handles object references. In Python, when you create a dictionary and assign it to a variable, you're not storing the dictionary in the variable. Instead, you're storing a reference to the dictionary.

In your code, `MokeDex[name]= MokeBeast` isn't copying the dictionary `MokeBeast` into `MokeDex[name]`. It's storing a reference to `MokeBeast` under the key `name` in the `MokeDex` dictionary. That means that every time you modify `MokeBeast`, you're actually modifying the dictionaries referred to in all entries of `MokeDex`, because they all refer to the same dictionary.

To fix this, you'll need to create a new dictionary for each beast. You can do this by copying the dictionary inside the loop:

```py
MokeDex = {}
MokeBeast = {"type":None, "specialmove":None,  "startingHP":None,"startingMP":None}

while True:
  name = input("Input your beast's name >")
  new_beast = MokeBeast.copy()
  for key in new_beast.keys():
    new_beast[key] = input(f"Input your beast's {key} >")

  MokeDex[name]= new_beast
  check = input("Do you want to add another beast? y/n>")
  if check == "n":
    break
```

In this code, `new_beast = MokeBeast.copy()` creates a new dictionary that's a copy of `MokeBeast`, and all changes are made to `new_beast`. This ensures that each beast in `MokeDex` is a separate dictionary.

Comment: Wow thank you! This is such a detailed and amazing answer. I wish I had some way to give you a gold star, If I could I definitely would.